# No dialog box on exiting html page

Tags: html

My book says that the below code will show a message box when I close the browser, navigate to a different page or refresh the page. It does not happen ! Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <title>Body attributes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<head>

</head>

    <body onload="window.alert('Greetings!')"
          onunload="window.alert('...Goodbye')">
    <h1>Loaded</h1>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to google!</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hit F12 to see if there are any messages in the console.

Comment: @mplungjan: By the time the console’d have opened, you’d have finished exiting that page, so that’s not really a viable option.

Comment: @icktoofay - that does not make sense. Open the console, navigate and see whatever messages appear.

Comment: @mplungjan: By default, most browsers will clear the console once they begin loading a new page. I suppose if you can toggle that option, it’s not such a bad idea, but if you can’t, it’s not going to do you any good since you might see a message and then have it immediately disappear.

Comment: No problems in my browsers

Answer (score 1):

If you could run arbitrary code for an arbitrarily long amount of time when closing the page, that could be an opportunity for abuse. I wouldn’t be surprised if older browsers supported it, but new browsers stopped supporting it for security reasons.

If you want to prompt someone whether they really want to exit the web page, you can use `onbeforeunload`, returning a prompt message:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return 'I\'ll miss you!';">
```

Comment: Sounds like a good reason. Learning this feature was not really important to me. But, its good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have imposed limitations on what may be executed in an `unload` event handler. IE 11 still lets you open a new window there, but Chrome and Firefox don’t; they ignore your call to `window.alert` there. Chrome describes this in the console log: “Blocked alert('...Goodbye') during unload.” This means that there is not much you can do in an `unload` event handler, even though the event is still created and can be handled.

Instead, you can handle the [`unbeforeunload` event](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload.html), which is created before the actual unload starts. This event, implemented first in IE 4 and then copied by other browser vendors, has now been defined in the HTML5 spec, clause 5.6.11 [Unloading documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#unloading-documents). Using it, you still cannot create windows as you like, but browsers show a dialog to the user. The dialog is created by the browser, in a browser-specific manner. You can try to inject your own message into it by making your event handler return it as value, but Firefox intentionally ignores such requests.

```html
    <body onload="window.alert('Greetings!')"
          onbeforeunload="return '...Goodbye'">
    <h1>Loaded</h1>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to google!</a>
```